# Removing index.php from website URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am using the Kohana framework (but I think it's irrelevant for this question) and pages can be accessed like so

```
http://www.example.com/articles/
http://www.example.com/index.php/articles/
```

Now, as a rule of thumb, I generally try and tweak my .htaccess to only allow one way in for a page, and silently redirect other common ways.

Essentially, in the 1st URL above, the address is actually internally redirected to the 2nd example.

What I want to do, is to force any URLs of the 2nd type to turn into URLs of the first type. I'm not often confident in .htaccess, and my first attempt is throwing some unexpected results (like endless loops on occasion)

Here is what I've came up with

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*) $1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and if you've also ran into this problem, how have you solved it?

**EDIT**

I've decided to post my entire .htaccess so all of my redirects can be examined.

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /~toberua/


# file not found page
    ErrorDocument 404 /404/
    ErrorDocument 403 /403/

# get people out of my directories
    Options -Indexes

# default page to load
    DirectoryIndex index.php

# add trailing slash if missing
    RewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/ [NC,R=301,L]

# redirect /favicon.ico requests
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/layout/favicon\.ico [NC]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} favicon\.(gif|ico|png|jpe?g) [NC]
     RewriteRule (.*) images/layout/favicon.ico [R=301,L]

# send /home back to TLD
     RewriteRule home/ $1  [NC,R=301,L]

# ensure there is no /index.php in the address bar
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ $1 [R=301,L] # this was my attempt to stop /dir/index.php and make it simply /dir/

    RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*) $1 [NS,NC,L,R=301]

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(application|modules|system) - [F,L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*) $1 [NS,NC,L,R=301]
```

What you're not processing is that *all* requests are subject to rewriting, and when you do a rewrite it generate a subrequest -- which is also subject to rewriting.   So you wind up rewriting /articles to /index.php/articles, then in the subrequest that that issue, you rewrite /index.php/articles to /articles and generate a new request for the 301 redirect, on and on.  Adding the NS flag will make this rule not operate on subrequests, which I think should fix your problem, unless you're also doing a 301 on the /articles -> /index.php/articles rewrite (but that would be madness).

Comment: In response to you edit: Do you think I need to setup a RewriteCond? I tried adding that flag and it's still looping. Any suggestions? +1 for your troubles :)

Comment: I don't think a RewriteCond is necessary or helpful, no.  I can't see why the continued loops are happening without seeing the rules you're using to rewrite /articles/ to /index.php/articles.

Comment: Let me add some more to my question.

Comment: Yeah, adding NS should definitely stop the loops.  Is this in a .htaccess, or is it in a vhost conf file or something where you could conceivably have forgotten to kick Apache to get the modified rule in place?

Comment: This is .htaccess . I'm using a few other rewrites above it, I'll try and single out which rewrites aren't playing nice.

Comment: K.  You could also experiment with disabling Kohana's PT flag.  That shouldn't be hurting anything, but if you don't turn up anything obvious then it's another variable to eliminate.

Comment: I've posted my entire .htaccess. Thanks for looking into this Chaos.

Comment: Well, the immediate suspect would be your other bizarre rule rewriting index.php-related requests.  Try adding NS to that too.

Comment: Damn, she is still looping! I even commented that entire thing out and no luck.

Comment: Wow.  Wacky.  Well, it's pretty much time to comment out everything but the basic Kohana rewrites and start re-adding things one at a time.

Comment: Alright, will comment again when I can tell what is happening.

Comment: Chaos, I removed everything except the default Kohana .htaccess and added your rule in beneath the RewriteBase and it is still looping... Should I have a RewriteCond which detects index.php in the URL ?

Comment: I got it working Chaos! I added this line above RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php(.*)\ HTTP/ [NC]

Comment: Alex, you should post this as an answer... Thanks though!