# .htaccess Edge Case

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am using these rules and conditions in .htaccess to turn these

```
http://www.example.com/index.php/about/history
http://www.example.com/about/history/index.php
```

into

```
http://www.example.com/about/history
```

.htaccess

```
# ensure there is no /index.php in the address bar
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ $1 [R=301,L,NS]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php(.*)\ HTTP/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*) $1 [NS,NC,L,R=301]
```

Except there is a case where if the URL is

```
http://www.example.com/about/index.php/history/
```

It will result in an endless loop of redirecting. Now I know this is probably a rarity, but I'd like it not to happen if possible. How can I change my rules to accomodate this?

[More info here about my .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905030/removing-index-php-from-website-urls/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you just want to remove index.php whereever it appears? In that case your solution is overly complex. You probably want something like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php/(.*)$ $1$2 [NS,NC,L,R=301]
```

This should be the only rule, no need for the RewriteCond's as well

Comment: This rule doesn't work where the URL starts with index.php/something like in the 1st example. It does work with the other examples, however.

Comment: moved the slash to the back of the index.php string. does it match now?

Comment: note. it could now technically match my_index.php as well but I suspect that's unlikely to happen