# Hide index.php for "https" connection?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, url-rewriting, symfony-1.4

I want to hide "index.php" from the URL but it doesn't work at all. I have tried lot of stuff through google, stack but it did not help me at all. I have the following rules specified in my .htaccess file. Also when I access the URL using "https://www.domain.com/index.php/login" it works fine but when I access the site using "https://www.domain.com/login" then it shows 404 page (Page not found). I am not sure if I am missing something. [Note: I am using symfony 1.4, I also tried using the filters like http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/lapeSSLFilterPlugin for handling ssl but it doesn't work. I have also checked the error log for ssl but I am not getting any relevant error in the log.]

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

   # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
   # getting no_script_name to work
   RewriteBase /

   # we skip all files with .something
   #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
   #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
   #RewriteRule .* - [L]

   # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
   RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
   RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

   # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
   RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}        [R=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The ssl.conf file contains the below entires:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 443

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain/web
  ServerName www.domain.com
  RewriteEngine On
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  Alias /sf /var/www/html/domain/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/var/www/html/domain/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from All
  </Directory>
  <Directory "/var/www/html/domain/web">
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from All
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
  TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
  LogLevel warn

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/domain.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/domain.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/gd_bundle.crt
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/gd_bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

The httpd.conf file contains the below vhost settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.domain.com
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/domain/web"
   DirectoryIndex index.php
   RewriteEngine On
   <Directory "/var/www/html/domain/web">
     AllowOverride All
     Allow from All
   </Directory>
   Alias /sf /var/www/html/domain/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
   <Directory "/var/www/html/domain/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from All
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/905030/212940?

Comment: Look at the accepted answer, it should work for you too. If you read my comment carefully you'll see a '?' at the end which means it is a question. It was meant to help you, so don't get upset.

Comment: @vascowhite:apology. I tried that as well but it did not help. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probles is in you symfony configuration.
All apache config files is ok.

You need add this in global security.yml

```
default:
  is_secure: false
  is_ssl: true
```

sfGuardAuth/config/security.yml

```
secure:
  is_secure: false
  is_ssl: true

signin:
  is_secure: false
  is_ssl: true

signout:
  is_secure: false
```

And if you want no "index.php" in your URLs set

```
no_script_name:         true
```

in your global app settings.yml

Comment: be careful, it's coming from a plugin, not from symfony itself.

Answer (score 0):

Is the site work without index.php and http (not https) ?

If the site isn't working in http without https, the problem could be on the symfony part. Could you show us your `apps/[your apps]/config/settings.yml` ? Particular look for the options [`no_script_name`](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/04-Settings#chapter_04_sub_no_script_name):

> The `no_script_name` setting determines whether the front controller
>   script name is prepended to generated URLs or not. By default, it is
>   set to `true` by the `generate:app` task for the `prod` environment of the
>   first application created.

Comment: The no_script_name is set to false for all environment. I guess I am missing something in ssl.conf or httpd.conf. can you please take a look

Comment: I don't see what could be wrong, is your site work on http without index.php ? Did you enable [mod_rewrite log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) (RewriteLog & RewriteLogLevel > 3)?

Comment: yes the site works fine without index.php when I use http connection. [i.e.: http://www.domain.com/login]. Also the Rewrite is enabled to 5.

Comment: I think it's better for every one if we can solve the problem here instead of in private. What does the RewriteLog file says about the 404?

Comment: :it cannot find the /login in "/var/www/html/domain/web/"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11233/discussion-between-mahavir-munot-and-j0k)